# I2C 1 light at a time`

Tags: pi-4, i2c, led, pwm

i am currently using the NCP5623 (I2C LED Driver) to light up my 5V 1A (as written on the box) RGB LED strip.

i followed the sample connection as shown on the datasheet of the NCP5623 and when i ran my code, only a faint red glow can be seen (i was trying to run a full white light). confused, i took out the cable that is connected to the red pwm, and my led strip became green. again, when i took out the green pwm cable, the led turned blue. yet when i place the red pwm cable back in, the led strip became faint red again.

my led strip is a 4 cable led strip, i doubt it is of a good brand but it is what my school provided me with. for the RGB cables (the first 3) i connected them to the I2C just as the datasheet shows. as for the last wire, i connected it to power which is running from the 5v pin of the reaspberry pi.

i read up and it says that the faint glow could be due to not enough power supply? but i thought it should be sufficient as the box says 5V 1A and the website says 5W. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: According to the spec sheet for the NCP5623, it has `90 mA Total LED Current Capability` - so, that's about 1/10th of your RGB strip

Comment: Welcome! Sorry I can't give you an accurate answer there are many unknown factors. Posting an annotated schematic showing all connections including power, ground, and power supplies will give you a fast answer without a lot of questions. Post links to technical information on the hardware parts. Sales links such as Amazon and Aliexpress are sales outlets and normally do not have the needed information.